# Webpack HtmlWebpackPlugin builds the wrong src Path

Tags: javascript, webpack, typo3, webpack-5, typo3-extensions

Im trying to setup Webpack5 with my Typo3 installation... So far so good. Everything works fine but the build process of image Paths in HTML files with html-loader.
Im think i have to set the html-loader to ignore the path on build. Because if i set the path in the template on typo3conf/ext/sitepackage/Resources/Public/Images/4.png Webpack is not finding the file on build

**The ImagePath in my HTML File is:**

```
../../../../../../public/typo3conf/ext/sitepackage/Resources/Public/Images/4.png
```

**The Path after build Process:**

```
../../../../../Public/Dist/Images/4dbd2c58e6e057af018e.png
```

**But it shoud be:**

```
./typo3conf/ext/sitepackage/Resources/Public/Dist/Images/4dbd2c58e6e057af018e.png
```

**My webpack config**

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './JavaScript/Src/main.js',
  mode: "development",
  output: {
   filename: 'JavaScript/bundle.js',
   path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'Dist'),
   clean: true,
   assetModuleFilename: 'Images/[name].[ext]'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      
        {
            test: /\.(s(a|c)ss)$/, 
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
         },
        {
          test: /\.(woff(2)?|eot|ttf|otf|svg|)$/,
          type: 'asset',   // <-- Assets module - asset
          parser: {
            dataUrlCondition: {
              maxSize: 8 * 1024 // 8kb
            }
          },
          generator: {  //If emitting file, the file path is
            filename: 'Fonts/[hash][ext][query]' 
          }
        },
        {
          test: /\.(?:ico|gif|png|jpg|jpeg|webp)$/i,
          type: 'asset/resource',  //<-- Assets module - asset/resource
          generator: {
            filename: 'Images/[hash][ext][query]'
          } 
        },
        {
          test: /\.html$/i,
          loader: "html-loader",
          options: {}, 
        },
    ],

    

  },

  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: '../Private/Partials/Page/Header.html',
      filename: '../../Private/Dist/Html/Partials/Page/Header.html',
      inject:false
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: '../Private/Partials/Page/Footer.html',
      filename: '../../Private/Dist/Html/Partials/Page/Footer.html',
      inject:false
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: '../Private/Layouts/Page/Default.html',
      filename: '../../Private/Dist/Html/Layouts/Page/Default.html',
      inject:false
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: '../Private/Templates/Page/Default.html',
      filename: '../../Private/Dist/Html/Templates/Page/Default.html',
      inject:false
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin ({filename: "../Dist/Css/[name].css" })
  ],


  
};
```

How can i achieve that Webpack is process my HTML Files and images with the right src path? Or manipulate the src path on/after build

Answer (score 0):

If you use templates the path to the template is not available in the frontend (or backend) as it is used in a php file as data. If you include something (script, images, ...) with the relativ path from the template it points into nirvana.

Have absolute paths (from domain-root) or use viewhelper to generate proper paths in proper tags.